# How to store references of different class types in an array

Tags: java

I'd like to store references to classes (not objects) in an array such that i can use this to create multiple objects of different types. e.g.,

```java
class A;
class B;
class C;

array_of_classes = [A, B, C]; // How do I write this?

// Such that I can use it like this
Object a = new array_of_classes[0]();
```

Comment: create an array of class references using the  syntax Class<?>[] arrayOfClasses = {A.class, B.class, C.class};

Comment: makes sense. can you provide link to a doc or something? you can put this as an answer if you want.

Comment: But you can’t use the `new` keyword with a class object. You have to use reflection as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the example with reflection looks reasonable:

```java
List<Class<?>> classes = List.of(A.class, B.class, C.class);

for(Class<?> clazz : classes)
    Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
```

But I think this can be improved with using `Supplier` an not using Reflection:

```java
List<Supplier<Object>> suppliers = List.of(A::new, B::new, C::new);

for(Supplier<Object> supplier : suppliers)
    Object obj = supplier.get();
```

I find it more flexible and more OOP support.

Comment: so this approach with Supplier, will not use reflection?

Comment: @A.K. not it does not

Answer (score 6):

In Java you can create an array of class references using the syntax

```
Class<?>[] arrayOfClasses = {A.class, B.class, C.class};
```

and access them as below using newInstance()

```
Object a = arrayOfClasses[0].newInstance();
```

You can find the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using a no-args default constructor to create a new instance of a given `Class` as the `Class#newInstance` method becomes deprecated as of Java 9. Remember it uses reflection under the hood which is quite slow and should be avoided if possible. Perhaps you want to disclose what you try to achieve.

```java
private static Object newInstance(final Class<?> type) {
    try {
        Object object = type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        System.out.println("Created a new instance of " + object.getClass());
        return object;
    } catch (InstantiationException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

```java
static class A {}
static class B {}
static class C {}
```

---

The array declaration and usage are simple, but I recommend using a `List<Class<?>>`:

```java
List<Class<?>> classes = List.of(A.class, B.class, C.class);
List<Object> list = classes.stream().map(Application::newInstance).toList();
```

> ```
> Created a new instance of class com.company.Application$A
> Created a new instance of class com.company.Application$B
> Created a new instance of class com.company.Application$C
> ```

... or a single call:

```java
Object object = newInstance(classes.get(0));
```

> ```
> Created a new instance of class com.company.Application$A
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A more *functional* approach, without using Reflection.

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}

Supplier<?>[] arrayOfSupplier = { A::new, B::new, C::new };
// or
Supplier<?>[] arrayOfSupplier = { () -> new A(), () -> new B(), () -> new C() };
    
Object a = arrayOfSupplier[0].get();
```

`A::new` is a method reference to the no-argument constructor;
similar to the lambda expression `() -> new A()`.